# How to show that $G$ is nilpotent based on these conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, nilpotent-groups

Am trying to figure out a proof that if $G$ is a finite $p$-group, then $G$ is nilpotent ... Here,  nilpotent means that a group $G$ is nilpotent if there exists a series $1 = H_0 \leq H_1 \leq ... \leq H_n=G$, such that (1) $H_i$ is normal in $G$ for each $i=0...n$, and (2) $H_{i-1}/H_i \leq Z(G/H_{i-1})$, where $Z(G/H_{i-1})$ is the core of $G/H_{i-1}$.

So suppose that $G$ is a finite $p$-group. Let $Z(G)$ be the core of $G$. It can be shown that $Z(G) \neq 1$. Given that the quotient group $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent, we have that $G$ is nilpotent as well ...

Am trying to figure out the last statement, that is, if $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent, how does it follow that $G$ is nilpotent as well ?

Comment: Please add your definition of nilpotent, because for a certain definition this is trivial.

Comment: @SteveD, okay I added the definition

Comment: Since $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent, it has a central series according to your definition. Show that the series of subgroups in $G$ that statrts $ 1 < Z(G) < \cdots$ and contains the inverse images in $G$ of the central series of $G/Z(G)$ is a central series of $G$.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275368).

Comment: In standard group theory nomenclature, “the core” of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$; the core of $G$ would be $G$. But you use $Z(G)$, which is standard notation for the **center** of $G$, the set of all elements that commute with everything.